# Как создать queryset не из базы?

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

У меня есть `list<Class>` который я заполняю данными.

```
from django.db import models

class VM(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    uid = models.IntegerField()
    status = models.BooleanField()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Я хочу заполнить queryset своими значениями

```
class VMViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    list = []
    list.append( VM('axixa', 2,True))

    queryset =list 
    serializer_class = VMSerializer()
```

Как можно сделать такое?

Comment: почему нельзя .values_list('id', flat=True) и потом уже править созданный list?

Comment: Ничего не понятно

Comment: надо перевести queryset в list? и править?